# Error loading classes and failed to load map

Tags: android, maps

Last week I updated to android studios 8.0.1, to SDK Tools 23.0.2 and to the newest version of google play services (both in android studios and on the phone). Since then I haven't been able to load the map in my app, and I keep getting the error messages below.

```
07-07 08:55:24.343    2140-2140/com.example.mymapandroid.app.dev E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'gpr', referenced from method gps.a
07-07 08:55:24.359    2140-2140/com.example.mymapandroid.app.dev E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'gpr', referenced from method gps.a
07-07 08:55:24.359    2140-2140/com.example.mymapandroid.app.dev E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'gpr', referenced from method gps.a
07-07 08:55:24.640    2140-2140/com.example.mymapandroid.app.dev E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'ovx', referenced from method oyg.a
07-07 08:55:26.343    2140-2140/com.example.mymapandroid.app.dev E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method glt.a
07-07 08:55:52.000    2140-2522/com.example.mymapandroid.app.dev E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

I have tried to clean the project and then I have rebuilt it again. I also have reinstalled google play services on the phone but this doesn't help either. Does anyone have a clue how to solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to load it on emulator??

Comment: No I am trying to load it on an android phone.

Comment: What is RAM size of phone??

Comment: I think it is 150 MB..

Comment: I wonder ifit might be the SHA1 that is the problem, am I supposed to have gotten a different SHA1-number after updating android studios?

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your manifest? Sans API key, of course.

Your log looks almost identical to mine for a problem I've had recently, which was fixed by adding the following to the manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

I'm working on an application that was accessing maps just fine, then stopped out of the blue. I couldn't see anything actually pointing to a missing permission; I only picked up on it when I compared the manifest with another application that used maps api v2.

I had tried rolling back Google Play Services on my devices as well (from the latest 5.084, to 5.077), but to no avail. It was also around the same time as the SDK Tools 23.0.2 update, but pursuing that as the cause also turned up nothing.

I'm still confused as to why it previously worked without it (Google says you *need* the permission for maps to work). Perhaps I'd once put it there and accidentally deleted the line, but either way putting it in is what fixed it.

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/config